# Java JSP Using Include with Variable Parameters

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to pass a parameter to the jsp file that I am including in my main jsp. From what I've seen online the way to do this using c:set

```
approot/index.jsp

<c:set var="Arg01" value="Argument01"/>

<jsp:include page="include/other.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="myArg01" value="${Arg01}"/>
    <jsp:param name="myArg02" value="Argument02"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Although when I try to use the variables in the included jsp page only the one argument seems to be coming through (the second one which is not using c:set)

```
approot/include/other.jsp

<!-- this doesn't work -->
<p>${param.myArg01}</p>

<!-- this does -->
<p>${param.myArg02}</p>
```

Nothing crashes but I can see that myArg01 is blank

Comment: The second argument isn't using c:set just using a static string, that one works the first one doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of getting around it is probably awful but it's the only way I could find to get around the issue.

I used a different kind of include in my main JSP

```
public static String myArg01 = "Argument01";
public static String myArg02 = "Argument02";
<%@ include file="include/other.jsp" %>
```

Then I could reference the variables directly inside the included JSP file

```
<p><%= myArg01 %></p>
<p><%= myArg02 %></p>
```